# Identity Server 4 authentication with event bus

Tags: .net-core, microservices, identityserver4

I've got some architecture riddle for u: we all know that microservices are on the market for some time and if we talking about microservices architecture we commonly think about asynchronous communication between multiple components in system. Suppose that this communication is done using event bus (RabbitMq, M$ MQ, Kafka, etc). We also all know that IS4 is great component which abstracts sso in provided product. Let's think of that case: we have microservice #1 (webapi) which publishes event to external event bus, there are also microservice #2 which subscribes to same bus and processes events published by service #1.

So there is a question: how to authenticate published messages in is4? On what level they should be authenticated? I have some thoughts but I'd like to hear what is your expiriences in gaining this functionality.

Comment: Presumably messages that require authentication to create only get onto the bus when an already-authenticated user makes a call to the API, so the message doesn't need to be authenticated after that; it's implicit. If you need to know the identity of the user who created the message you can just store it in the message, but a subsequent trip to IS4 shouldn't be required. What exactly are you trying to authenticate to what and for what purpose?

Comment: I was thinking about checking if message is authenticated on subscriber side so message published by api should contain some authentication info like Bearer header in rest, maybe it could be decrypted access token. Subscriber could receive this message and get access token from message then query user info or introspection to check if access token is still valid.